# Embedded DNS stops working after installing and starting firewalld on CentOS 7 container

Tags: docker, centos7, firewalld, docker-compose

I have two dockers that run from docker compose:

```
version: "3"
services:
  sqa:
    image: sqa
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    hostname: sqa
    networks:
      - robottest_net
    tty: true
  slave:
    image: slave
    ports:
      - "8270:8270"
    hostname: slave
    cap_add:
      - ALL
    privileged: false
    networks:
      - robottest_net
networks:
  robottest_net:
```

Both of images based on centos7. In the slave installed firewalld service with default settings and entrypoint is /usr/sbin/init

From sqa I can ping slave but from slave I cannot.

```
ping: sqa: Name or service not known
```

How to configure firewalld centos docker image to solve the issue or maybe docker compose needs to change?

Logs from /var/log/firewalld

```
2019-02-06 15:46:25 WARNING: ip6tables not usable, disabling IPv6 firewall.
2019-02-06 15:46:25 WARNING: ebtables not usable, disabling ethernet bridge firewall.
```

**DETAILS:**

I found more described issue but it not resolved yet: https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/35095

If someone now about it, please help

**WORKAROUND:**

To add Google DNS when slave service started:

```
echo "nameserver 8.8.4.4" >> /etc/resolv.conf
echo "nameserver 8.8.8.8" >> /etc/resolv.conf
```

And add static IP to sqa and slave in the yaml then use it for slave

```
  extra_hosts:
      - "sqa:172.127.0.2"
```

Comment: why do you need a firewall in a container?

Comment: Using it for running and testing our internal applications in firewalld environment

Comment: I am also facing this issue. Is it resolved?